# How would I access this with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<label for="102-0-0">0</label>
```

I've never seen the for tag before, I'm pretty new to programming in general so I'm sorry if this is a dumb question.

I've tried googling it and I can't find a solution on how to access this specific line of code.

Comment: What do you mean by access this specific line?

Comment: if you need a css selector try the following: `label[for="102-0-0"]`

Comment: Sorry, I just meant by that that I don't know how to access that specific tag. (the for tag)

Comment: For is an attribute of the label tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this :

```js
var a = document.querySelector("label[for='102-0-0']").innerHTML;
console.log(a); //content of label tag

a = document.querySelector("label").getAttribute('for');
console.log(a); //content of the attribute for
```

```css
label[for='102-0-0'] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label for="102-0-0">10</label>
```

This also available with any **attribute** (as `for` is simply an attribute of `lablel` ). You can read more about [HTML attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp)

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName(label)` however to select all of them you would need to put it in a loop, or if you want just one write the index of what position this label has on your page.

Alternatively give it an `id` or a `class` and use that!